# How to save files into AWS using signedURLs and ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, pre-signed-url

I'm trying to attach images with regular text inputs into my form in order to submit to my MongoDB.

This is what my function to create a post looks like:

```
  const [postData, setPostData] = useState({
    text: '',
    images: null,
    postedto: auth && auth.user.data._id === userId ? null : userId
  });

  const { text, images, postedto } = postData;

  const handleChange = name => e => {
    setPostData({ ...postData, [name]: e.target.value, images: e.target.files });
  };

  const createPost = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await addPost(postData, setUploadPercentage);
  };
```

From there I move into my action addPost; on this function I call two API routes:

```
// @route       POST api/v1/posts
// @description Add post
// @access      Private
// @task        DONE
export const addPost = (formData, setUploadPercentage) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    // ATTACH FILES
    let fileKeys = [];

    for(let file of formData.images) {
      const uploadConfig = await axios.get(`${API}/api/v1/uploads/getS3url?type=${file.type}`);
      
      await axios.put(uploadConfig.data.url, file, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': file.type
        }
      });

      fileKeys.push(uploadConfig.data.key);
    }

    console.log(fileKeys);

    // INSERT NEW BLOG
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; application/json'
      },
      onUploadProgress: ProgressEvent => {
        setUploadPercentage(
          parseInt(Math.round(ProgressEvent.loaded * 100) / ProgressEvent.total)
        );
        // Clear percentage
        setTimeout(() => setUploadPercentage(0), 10000);
      }
    };

    formData.images = fileKeys;

    const res = await axios.post(`${API}/api/v1/posts`, formData, config);
    
    dispatch({
      type: ADD_POST,
      payload: res.data
    });

    dispatch(setAlert('Post Created', 'success'));
  } catch (err) {
    const errors = err.response && err.response.data.errors;

    if (errors) {
      errors.forEach(error => dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, 'danger')));
    }

    dispatch({
      type: POST_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: err.response && err.response.statusText, status: err.response && err.response.status }
    });
  }
};
```

My getS3url function looks exactly like this:

```
exports.uploadFile = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { type } = req.query;
  const fileExtension = type.substring(type.indexOf('/') + 1);
  const key = `${process.env.WEBSITE_NAME}-${req.user._id}-${
    req.user.email
  }-${Date.now().toString()}.${fileExtension}`;

  const params = {
    Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: key,
    ContentType: type
  };

  s3.getSignedUrl(`putObject`, params, (err, url) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(
        new ErrorResponse(
          `There was an error with the files being uploaded`,
          500
        )
      );
    }

    return res.status(201).json({ success: true, key: url });
  });
});
```

I would like to point out that every post might have more than one image file and  the function should return a signedURL for each single file; let's say I upload two files, I then should have two URLS retrieved in order to attach them into my post.

I'm sure there's nothing wrong with the way I;m managing state to submit data because it always return what I expect when using on `console.log(postData)` , even the files are shown.

Now I'm assuming the problem resides on my action, especially the code before the `/// INSERT NEW BLOG` comment because when I `console.log(fileKeys)` nothing is returned, not even an error/undefined/null.....I mean just nothing!.

My uploadFile is working fine when used with a single file....well not really because yes, it returns an URL of the 'supposed' uploaded file but when I get into my AWS console/bucket, there's nothing..but thats for its own post.

**What I need help with?**

Well, I'm trying to upload one/multiple files into my AWS using signedURL to return them as strings and attach them into my post. Is there any problem with my action file?.

Thanks!!.

Comment: you need use putObject upload file into s3. After upload is success, you can get signed URL.

Comment: Yes, I know that my application already returns the URL but for a single flie, I'm looking to return a string for each single file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found my own solution, here it is:

```
export const addPost = (formData, images, setUploadPercentage) => async dispatch => {
  try {

    let fileKeys = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      
      /// STEP 3
      const token = localStorage.getItem("xAuthToken");
      api.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`

      const uploadConfig = await api.get(`/uploads/getS3url?name=${images[i].name}&type=${images[i].type}&size=${images[i].size}`);

      // STEP 1
      delete api.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'];

      await api.put(uploadConfig.data.postURL, images[i], {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': images[i].type
        }
      });

      fileKeys.push(uploadConfig.data.getURL);
    }

    // INSERT NEW BLOG
    const config = {
      onUploadProgress: ProgressEvent => {
        setUploadPercentage(
          parseInt(Math.round(ProgressEvent.loaded * 100) / ProgressEvent.total)
        );
        setTimeout(() => setUploadPercentage(0), 10000);
      }
    };

    // STEP 2
    const token = localStorage.getItem("xAuthToken");
    api.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`

    const res = await api.post(`/posts`, {...formData, images: fileKeys}, config);
    
    dispatch({
      type: ADD_POST,
      payload: res.data
    });

    dispatch(setAlert('Post Created', 'success'));
  } catch (err) {
    const errors = err.response && err.response.data.errors;

    if (errors) {
      errors.forEach(error => dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, 'danger')));
    }

    dispatch({
      type: POST_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: err.response && err.response.statusText, status: err.response && err.response.status }
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

for my case, I have been looping through the images and generating signed URLs and returning them since s3 doesn't support the signed URL option for multiple files at once.

Comment: dont worry dude, I solved it long ago. You can check my answer.